# How to iterate over certain columns of a pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `data` that has 27 columns. I need to iterate over 6 of those columns.

For each iteration, I am simply printing out the elements, so the dataframe will not be mutated. Note that the way in which each row is printed is specialized and I can't print all the rows simultaneously.

I am wondering what is the best approach to do this?

Comment: `print( df[list_of_columns_you_want_to_print] )` ?

Comment: @SomeDude The print is a bit more complicated. We have a specialized function that does this, and we can't print all the rows simultaneously. it has to to be one at a time

Comment: Then just:  `for row in df[your_lst_columns].iterrows(): special_print(row)`

Answer (score 0):

put it here sicne it won't fit in comment .
you need to clarify better but are you looking for something like this :

```
for column in df.columns:
    print(df[column])
```